# Are there any functions which were discovered only after we considered their integrands?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

For example, if we didn't knew about the existence of inverse trigonometric functions before dealing with the integrands $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, $\frac{dx}{{1+x^2}}$, and $\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ then we would have needed to define the inverse trigonometric functions in a totally novel first time.

Comment: I think that "discovered" isn't the right word. "defined" would be better. The "special functions" were defined when the previously known functions are insufficient in various kind of problems : some integrals, some ODEs, solving some equations, etc. : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Comment: You could say generalized functions or "distributions"  were discovered after considering their integral.  They aren't defined in a way that you can evaluate them at a point,  but only make since when you're considering their integral